# Symbol Selector has Save As button grayed out?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.3, update

I upgraded to 10.3 from 10.2.  I tried to SAVE a symbol but the SAVE AS button is grayed out, rendering saving as not possible.  I've tried rebooting, re-opening the mxd... What solutions are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to check your `username.style` file to see if you have write access to it, or if it's even there.

By default, it's under:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcMap\username.style`

You can also go to `Customize -> Style Manager` to see if your `.style` file is referenced properly.

Comment: I solved it by re-downloading the 10.3.1 upgrade 2 additional times.  The 2nd time "fixed" the problem.  I did not try the answer provided by Mintx as I was re downloading and I just checked my question. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

ESRI has a support article for this issue: [Problem: Unable to save customized symbols in the Symbol Selector](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012396). The first solution (renaming the Normal template) worked for me.